# How to migrate from send to writev?

Tags: c, sockets

I have many

```
send(fd, buf, len, MSG_DONTWAIT | MSG_NOSIGNAL)
```

which I want to combine into one

```
writev(fd, iov, iovcnt)
```

However, `writev` does not recognize the `flags` argument. How can I set the socket options in this case?

Comment: Ignore the `SIGPIPE` signal, that takes care of the `MSG_NOSIGNAL` flag. And make the socket non-blocking for the `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look up the `sendmsg` syscall. It has all the features of `send` plus all the features of `writev` (plus some other stuff which you won't use but that's OK)

Comment: Unfortunately with `sendmsg` I get "Message to long". I suppose this is because the data has to fit into one ip packet which has to fit into one ethernet frame?

Comment: My last comment is not true. I messed up data size and iovcnt. `sendmsg` is the solution.

Comment: Is it a datagram or a stream socket? (UDP or TCP?) I assumed TCP when I read your question, in which case the network-layer packet size shouldn't matter. In the case of UDP, I don't know if there is a way to send multiple packets in a single syscall.

Comment: Oh, you'll also want to beware of the `IOV_MAX` limit

Answer (score 3):

You can't map this directly to writev(), you'd have to use [sendmsg](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendmsg)() to accomplish that, as sendmsg() will allow you to do scatter-getter sends, and include the same flags as send(). However you can get almost the same behavior as these 2 flags:

MSG_NOSIGNAL indicates that the call should not deliver a SIGPIPE signal in case of a send/write error, you will get the same behavior for writev by ignoring the SIGPIPE signal:

```
  signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_IGN);
```

This is process wide though, and affects all file descriptors.

MSG_DONTWAIT is requesting a non-blocking send. For writev, you'll have to set the socket to non-blocking - which you'd normally do just once per file descriptor:

```
int flags = fcntl(fd,F_GETFL,NULL);
if(flags < 0 ) {
    return flags;
}
return fcntl(fd,F_SETFL,flags | O_NONBLOCK);
```